# how to combine results to get number of teams against whom Arsenal won all the available six points

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'home' that is storing Arsenal football club's performance in the league at home in 2003-04 season, while the table 'away' stores Arsenal's performance away in the same season.

```
Table `home`:

Opponent           Goal_Scored      Goal_Conceded
Everton                2                 1
Aston Villa            2                 0
Portsmouth             1                 1
Newcastle United       3                 2
Chelsea                2                 1
Tottenham Hotspur      2                 1
Fulham                 0                 0
Blackburn Rovers       1                 0
Wolverhampton Wonderers 3                0
Middlesbrough          4                 1


Table `away`:

Opponent           Goal_Scored      Goal_Conceded
Everton                1                 2
Aston Villa            2                 2
Portsmouth             1                 2
Newcastle United       2                 3
Chelsea                2                 2
Tottenham Hotspur      2                 3
Fulham                 2                 0
Blackburn Rovers       1                 2
Wolverhampton Wonderers 3                2
Middlesbrough          1                 4
```

Note that a team is **awarded three points for a win, one for a draw and zero for a loss**.

I wanted to determine the number of teams against whom Arsenal won all the available six points.

And for that purpose, I have written a partial code:

```
CREATE TABLE home (
    Opponent varchar(60),
    Goal_Scored int(8),
    Goal_Conceded int(8)
);

CREATE TABLE away (
    Opponent varchar(60),
    Goal_Scored int(8),
    Goal_Conceded int(8)
);

INSERT INTO home (Opponent, Goal_Scored, Goal_Conceded)
VALUES 
("Everton",2,1),
("Aston Villa",2,0),
("Portsmouth",1,1),
("Newcastle United",3,2),
("Chelsea",2,1),
("Tottenham Hotspur",2,1),
("Fulham",0,0),
("Blackburn Rovers",1,0),
("Wolverhampton Wonderers",3,0),
("Middlesbrough",4,1);


INSERT INTO away (Opponent, Goal_Scored, Goal_Conceded)
VALUES
("Everton",1,2),
("Aston Villa",2,2),
("Portsmouth",1,2),
("Newcastle United",2,3),
("Chelsea",2,2),
("Tottenham Hotspur",2,3),
("Fulham",2,0),
("Blackburn Rovers",1,2),
("Wolverhampton Wonderers",3,2),
("Middlesbrough",1,4);
```

and to get the combined result, I tried the below code but it did not produce the expected result:

```
select a.opponent
from home a 
where a.goals_scored > a.goals_conceded
union all
select b.opponent
from away b 
where b.goals_scored > b.goals_conceded
```

But then how I should combine the results to **get number of teams against whom Arsenal won all the available six points**

Comment: In simpler terms you need to look for teams where goals_scored > goals_conceded rather than actually computing and summing the points, and you'll need to [join the two tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). Do you know how to join yet?

Comment: (That said, you can compute the points for both tables as subqueries - or CTEs in MySQL 8+ - and then join them if you prefer. But you don't need to, you just need to find the winners from each table.)

Comment: actually, i need to join, because, in the end, I have to find all those teams only, against whom Arsenal received all the 6 points (3 points for win at home and 3 points for the win at away)... actually, you are right, goals_scored > goals_conceded should be good enough to arrive on join things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a solution here's the join solution:

```sql
select opponent
from home
join away using (opponent)
where home.goal_scored > home.goal_conceded
  and away.goal_scored > away.goal_conceded;
```

where we join the home and away records for each team and then filter out anything where Arsenal didn't win both legs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to check about points for your requirement.
The condition should be that the for the same opponent `Goal_Scored > Goal_Conceded` is true:

```
SELECT Opponent
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM home WHERE Goal_Scored > Goal_Conceded
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM away WHERE Goal_Scored > Goal_Conceded
) t
GROUP BY Opponent
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- for 2 matches against the same opponent
```

If you want just the number of teams, then aggregation with `EXISTS` would be better:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_teams 
FROM home h
WHERE h.Goal_Scored > h.Goal_Conceded
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM away a WHERE a.Opponent = h.Opponent AND a.Goal_Scored > a.Goal_Conceded)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5fbc915a368dbce119a4f2d1d98b1408).

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly, here is how you can do it :

```
select t.Opponent, sum(CASE WHEN goal_scored - goal_conceded > 0 THEN 3
WHEN goal_scored - goal_conceded = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) points 
from 
( SELECT * FROM home a
  union all
  SELECT * FROM away a
) t
group by Opponent
having points = 6;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=405cac770f8a886faee140c838b9cc92)*

Comment: thanks for sharing... just curious to know if it can also be possible using `where a.goal_scored > a.goal_conceded` because mathematically this condition also gives 3 points for win at home and 3 points win when away. and hence count the number of teams against which they got win at home as well as win when away???

Comment: yes that's also possible, see Rup's answer